# Sanitizing SQL fstring query for psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, sanitization

I'm iteratively building up my SQL query to execute as such:

```
        sql = "SELECT * FROM txs "

        param_values = []
        if params:
            sql += f"WHERE name=%s" 
            param_values.append(params.name)
        
        ...

        with _psql_connection() as c:
            c.execute(sql, (*param_values)
            return c.fetchall()
```

It seems as though me using the fstring to append the name is injectable, and I'm not sure what the right solution here is. Shouldn't `c.execute(sql, (*param_values)` sanitize the input already ?

Comment: It is all spelled out in the docs. For [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).. For dynamically building queries [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).

Comment: I'd appreciate an example for my usecase!

Comment: From the `psycopg2` docs that Adrian linked you to. "Warning: Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint." You should be able to find all of your answers in the links he provided. What if for `param_values` I pass in `; DROP DATABASE x;`

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2 
from psycopg2 import sql 
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres')

params = True
sql_str = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM txs ")
where_str = sql.SQL("WHERE name=%s")

param_values = []
if params:
    sql_str = sql.Composed([sql_str, where_str])
    param_values.append(params.name)

print(sql_str.as_string(con))
SELECT * FROM txs WHERE name=%s


with con.cursor() as c:
  c.execute(sql_str, param_values)
  return c.fetchall()
```